# Whats wrong with this trigger

Tags: trigger

Whats is wrong with this below code instead of using String.isBlank method for the loop.

```java
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert) {
    for(Lead leadRecord : Trigger.new){
        if(leadRecord.LeadSource == ' '){
            leadRecord.LeadSource = 'Other';
        }
    }
}
```

help appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a trigger, a text field will never be a string containing only spaces or an empty string. It will always be null. The correct code is:

```
if(leadRecord.LeadSource == null){
```

Comment: Does it matter that `LeadSource` is a picklist?

Comment: @DerekF Yes, I realize it's a picklist, and no, it doesn't matter that it's a picklist. All fields that hold text (phone, Id, long text area, picklist, whatever) can't store strings of only spaces, and during saving/loading to/from the database, will end up being a null value instead of an empty string or a string with only whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! for that explanation @sfdcfox

Answer (score 3):

`' '` is a string literal for precisely 1 space.

Space is a character, just the same as 'g', 't', or '\n'.
An empty string has precisely 0 characters.
Null and empty are not the same.

You should be using `isBlank()` because:

- It's provided by Salesforce (meaning you don't need to test it)
- It's short
- It returns true if your string is either null or empty